# What should be the java code for rest-assured api for getting the access token

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I want to get access token from the given REST-API call.
I have tested this in postman and it is working fine which needs data to be entered in all 3 tabs( Authorization, Header and body and need to fire post method). Please find the attached screenshots for better clarity.
Please guide me how to automate this with java and jayaway restassured library or any other solution.

[Postman screenshot- Authorization tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjgai.png)

[Postman Screenshot - Header tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUPUr.png)

[Postman screenshot- Body tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuEwr.png)

Note: Username and password is different in Authorization and in different in Body tab

Answer (score 0):

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://URI";
Response res = given().header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body("{" + "   \"username\":\"yourmail@something.com\"," + "   \"password\":\"ab@1234\""
                        + "}")
                .when().post("/api/token").then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();
String responseString = res.asString();
System.out.println(responseString);
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(responseString);
String str = js.get("data.access_token");
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your response will look like this:

```
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAA%2FAAA%3DAAAAAAAA"}
```

You can try following Rest Assured example:

```
JsonPath jsonPath = RestAssured.given()
    .auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password")
    .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .formParam("username", "johndoe")
    .formParam("password", "12345678")
    .formParam("grant_type", "password")
    .formParam("scope", "open_d")
    .when()
    .post("http://www.example.com/oauth2/token")
    .then()
    .statusCode(200)
    .contentType("application/json")
    .extract().jsonPath();

String tokenType = jsonPath.getString("token_type");
String accessToken = jsonPath.getString("access_token");
```

Comment: Now after collecting access token from this request.. I need to hit one more URL to get the remaining data in JSON format. for that what I am doing in postman is as below. 1. Postman Param tab : pass the "Customerid" 2.Postman Header tab : Request id ="$this is automatically genereted.. dont know how to pass this" , Ocp-Apim-Subscription-key="xyz", RequestingSystem="abc"; TargetSystem="pqr"; Authorization="Bearer {{token}} .. please guide me what should be the Java code for this.